# DOM appendChild not giving proper output

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to write a program where in addItem function, the input value will be appended to the checkbox and trying to append the checkbox and the inputted value in an ul through li. 
I am able to see the checkbox in the output but not the inputted value. However, in console log I am able to see the inputted value. Hence, I think something is wrong in the logic, but not able to figure out what.

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
let removeButton = document.getElementById('removeButton');
let ul;
let li;
let inputTag;

const addItem = () => {
  let getItem = input.value;
  ul = document.getElementById('list');
  li = document.createElement('li');
  inputTag = document.createElement('input');
  inputTag.type = 'checkbox';
  inputTag.id = 'check';


  let label = document.createElement('label');
  let newItem = document.createTextNode(getItem);
  console.log(newItem)
  label.appendChild(newItem);
  inputTag.appendChild(label);
  li.appendChild(inputTag);
  ul.appendChild(li);

  input.value = '';
}

const removeItem = () => {

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="controls">
      <h1>Todo App</h1>
      <input type="text" id="input">
      <button onclick=addItem() id="addButton">Add</button>
      <button id="removeButton">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <ul id="list">
      <li class="mycheck">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">Eat
      </li>
      <li class="mycheck">
        <input type="checkbox" checked id="check">Sleep
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of changes you may need to do

1. `addItem` in `<button onclick=addItem()` need to be inside quotes.
2. There are duplicate `id`. id should be unique.
3. You are appending `label` inside input. That is the reason you cannot see the label text.
4. Use `label` `for` attribute. Beside accessibility it will also check and uncheck the checkbox if you click on the text. For example if you click on `Eat` & `Sleep` text in your example , it will not make any change in the checkbox. But in this example if you create a checkbox through the input and click on the text you will see change in the state of the checkbox.

   5. In your code you are loading `script.js` befor other library files. This may cause an error if `script.js` have any dependency on the library. First load library then load custom files

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
let removeButton = document.getElementById('removeButton');
let ul;
let li;
let inputTag;

const addItem = () => {
  let getItem = input.value;
  console.log(getItem)
  ul = document.getElementById('list');
  li = document.createElement('li');
  inputTag = document.createElement('input');
  inputTag.type = 'checkbox';
  inputTag.id = 'check_' + getItem;
  let label = document.createElement('label');
  label.setAttribute('for', 'check_' + getItem)
  let newItem = document.createTextNode(getItem, );
  label.appendChild(newItem);
  //inputTag.appendChild(label);

  li.appendChild(inputTag);
  li.appendChild(label);
  ul.appendChild(li);

  input.value = '';
}

const removeItem = () => {

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Hello, world!</title>

<div class="container">

  <div class="controls">
    <h1>Todo App</h1>
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <button onclick="addItem()" id="addButton">Add</button>
    <button id="removeButton">Remove</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="list">
    <li class="mycheck">
      <input type="checkbox" id="check">Eat
    </li>
    <li class="mycheck">
      <input type="checkbox" checked id="checkSleep">Sleep
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

*input* elements are ***empty*** or ***void-elements***. Appending elements on them will not give you the proper result. Add the *label* element in *li* instead of the *input* element.

**Please Note:** The attribute [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique in a document, you can use [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) attribute instead.

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
let removeButton = document.getElementById('removeButton');
let ul;
let li;
let inputTag;

const addItem = () => {
  let getItem = input.value;
  ul = document.getElementById('list');
  li = document.createElement('li');
  inputTag = document.createElement('input');
  inputTag.type = 'checkbox';
  inputTag.class = 'check';

  let label = document.createElement('label');
  let newItem = document.createTextNode(getItem);
  //console.log(newItem)
  label.appendChild(newItem);
  li.appendChild(inputTag);
  li.appendChild(label);
  ul.appendChild(li);

  input.value = '';
}

const removeItem = () => {

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">

        <div class="controls">
          <h1>Todo App</h1>
          <input type="text" id="input">
          <button onclick=addItem() id="addButton">Add</button>
          <button id="removeButton">Remove</button>
        </div>
        <ul id="list">
          <li class="mycheck">
            <input type="checkbox" class="check">Eat
          </li>
          <li class="mycheck">
              <input type="checkbox" checked class="check">Sleep
            </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```